# why this left join query failed to load all the data in left table?

Tags: sql, mysql, left-join

users table

```
+-----+-----------+
| id  | username  |
+-----+-----------+
|   1 | tom       |
|   2 | jelly     |
|   3 | foo       |
|   4 | bar       |
+-----+-----------+
```

groups table

```
+----+---------+-----------------------------+
| id | user_id | title                       |
+----+---------+-----------------------------+
|  2 |       1 | title 1                     |
|  4 |       1 | title 2                     |
+----+---------+-----------------------------+
```

the query

```
SELECT users.username,users.id,count(groups.title) as group_count 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN groups 
ON users.id = groups.user_id
```

result

```
+----------+----+-------------+
| username | id | group_count |
+----------+----+-------------+
| tom      |  1 |           2 |
+----------+----+-------------+
```

where is the rest users' info? the result is the same as inner join , shouldn't left join return all left table's data?

PS:I'm using mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't you need a group by clause?

```
group by users.username,users.id
```

not knowing much about mysql but in mssql you would need this for it to run

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect the `group_count` column to be, had  all the users been returned? If you expected zero for users without groups, which would seem natural, how would it reach that result and still output at least one row?